# Excel Support Required

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data in a excel files which is in the below format:

```
+---------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Appname | R1 | R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R5 |
+---------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|     123 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  5 |  6 |  9 |
|     234 |  3 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 |
|     345 |  2 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 |  0 |
+---------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I need all the values under column R2 to R5 to appear under R1. So in the output file there will be only two columns i.e Appname and R1.

Any idea or help is appreciated.

Comment: Right now couldn't think of anything. I could have transposed indiviual rows from column R1 to R5, but there are 1000 entries so that would take a lot of time. And many a times coulmns could increase till R50.

Comment: Use `Power Pivot`, or `Data ► Get and Transform` to UNpivot the "R" columns.  Lots of examples here as to how to unpivot columns

Comment: As Ron stated, you can use Power Query to transform the data easily. Watch this short demo video. https://www.screencast.com/t/JEWywejao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

The code below assumes that your raw data is on a sheet called Sheet1. If it's not the case, change the sheet name in the code. The code will create a new sheet called "Output" with the data in the desired format.

```
Sub ReArrangeData()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, dlr As Long, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")      'Sheet with raw data
lr = sws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lc = sws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

On Error Resume Next
Set dws = Sheets("Output")
dws.Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

If dws Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=sws).Name = "Output"
    Set dws = ActiveSheet
End If

dws.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("AppName", "R1")
For i = 2 To lr
    dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    sws.Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy dws.Range("A" & dlr)
    dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    sws.Range(sws.Cells(i, 3), sws.Cells(i, lc)).Copy
    dws.Range("B" & dlr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Next i
On Error Resume Next
dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
dws.Range("A2:A" & dlr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
dws.Range("A2:A" & dlr).Value = dws.Range("A2:A" & dlr).Value
dws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Borders.Color = vbBlack
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Task Completed!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: your `dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1` is not fully qualified, you need to qualify the `Rows.Count` with `dws` worksheet as well, it should be `dlr = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1`, otherwise if "Output" sheet is not the `ActiveSheet`, `Rows.Count` will get it's value from the `ActiveSheet` (another worksheet)

Comment: Rows.Count will always return the max possible rows as per the version. In case of Excel 2013, it will always return 1048576 no matter if you qualify it with the sheet reference or not. It's unlike the range and cells where you need to qualify them with the sheet reference. Right?

Comment: it's about about the number, it's where `dws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1` is looking for the last cell with value in Column "B", if you don;t add `dws` before `Rows.Count` , it will look at the `ActiveSheet`, if `dws` is not the `ActivSheet` you will get a different `dlr` . You are welcome to test it

Comment: You are talking very strange, really. :) For your satisfaction, tested with two sheets, sheet1(sws) and sheet2(dws) where sheet1 is completely empty and sheet2 has data in the range B1:B50, while sheet1 was active sheet, I tested it (for your satisfaction only) and it returned 51. Maybe I have tested it wrong?